# Aligning text to the right in a table using Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

As part of my experimentation in learning Bootstrap, I created a table without actually using any of the tags that correspond to making a table. Instead, I used the grid system.  While it looks decent, I was wondering if there was a way to align the numbers to the right?  I have provided a JSFiddle link to show you what I came up with.  Any help or leads are appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/silosc/9jbd1rpw/2/

```html
<div class="container-xl">
  <div class="report-card-weekly-report">
    <div class="CompanyName">
      <h1>Weekly Summary for John's Groceries</h1>
      <h4> Week Ending: 01/20/2010</h4>
    </div>

    <br />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Number of Sales</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Total earnings</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Taxes charged</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Refunds</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Deliveries</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h2>Total numbers</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Numbers for the week</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        21,922
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        $0.00
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        $304,431.37
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        $0.00
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        $0.00
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<style>
  .CompanyName {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  h2 {
    color: orangered;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  
  p {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  
  p1 {
    text-align: right;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: If your problem is solved then make any of the following answers as accepted answer as both have the same solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `text-right` class of bootstrap:

```html
<div class="container-xl">
  <div class="report-card-weekly-report">
    <div class="CompanyName">
      <h1>Weekly Summary for John's Groceries</h1>
      <h4> Week Ending: 01/20/2010</h4>
    </div>

    <br />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Number of Sales</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Total earnings</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Taxes charged</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Refunds</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Deliveries</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h2>Total numbers</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Numbers for the week</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
        21,922
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
        $0.00
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
        $304,431.37
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
        $0.00
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
        $0.00
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<style>
  .CompanyName {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  h2 {
    color: orangered;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  
  p {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  
  p1 {
    text-align: right;
  }
</style>
```

See the JsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mhwgt9eq/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `text-right` property of bootstrap to align your desired text to the right. Here is a small piece of code to show you how it will work in your example.

```
  <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
       21,922
  </div>
```

similarly, you can also align the text to left with `text-left` property.